# Google Closure Library – Compilation Warnings

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I've been using the Google Closure Compiler for a few years but I haven't played with the actual Closure Library that much.

When I compile my app, I get the following warnings. The referenced code is in the library itself, not in my files. **I'm wondering whether I should do something to fix them or just wait for the Closure Library contributors to do that.**

```
/Users/Jan/.../closure-library/closure/goog/dom/dom.js:673:
  WARNING - Property type never defined on attributes
      delete attributes.type;
             ^

/Users/Jan/.../closure-library/closure/goog/dom/dom.js:2396:
  WARNING - assignment to property getFrameContentDocument of goog.dom.DomHelper.prototype
found   : function ((Element|null)): Document
required: function (this:goog.dom.DomHelper, (HTMLFrameElement|HTMLIFrameElement|null)): HTMLDocument
goog.dom.DomHelper.prototype.getFrameContentDocument =
^

/Users/Jan/.../closure-library/closure/goog/fx/animation.js:255:
  WARNING - mismatch of the stop property type and the type of the property it overrides from superclass goog.fx.TransitionBase
original: function (this:goog.fx.TransitionBase, boolean=): ?
override: function (this:goog.fx.Animation, boolean): ?
goog.fx.Animation.prototype.stop = function(gotoEnd) {
^
```

Nothing breaks as far as I can tell. The warnings do not pop for just one project but I do use the library the same way for all.

Comment: Are you using top of tree for both library and compiler?

Comment: Oh, thanks. I thought I was but it was the latest package in downloads rather than the current tip commit.

Comment: Do the warnings persist there?

Comment: No, it's all OK now. Thanks for the tip.